# using dup2 and pipe to redirect stdin

Tags: c, pipe, exec, dup2

I have a program A that takes two arguments from stdin and exits with a unique code depending on the arguments. I am writing a program B that calls program A using fork and exec and let program B print out the code program A exits with. For some reason, program A doesn't seem to be getting the data I piped through to it in the child process of fork. I'm not sure if I'm piping the correct data to the child process.

Could someone help me please? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
int program_B(void) {
char var_a[256];
char var_b[256];
int fd[2];

 // Read from stdin 
char *sendarray[2];
sendarray[0] = var_a;
sendarray[1] = var_b;


if(fgets(var_a, MAXLINE, stdin) == NULL) {
    perror("fgets");
    exit(1);
}

if(fgets(var_b, MAXLINE, stdin) == NULL) {
    perror("fgets");
    exit(1);
}

if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
  perror("pipe");
  exit(1);
}

int pid = fork();

// Child process -- error seems to be here. 
if (pid == 0) {

    close(fd[1]);

    dup2(fd[0], fileno(stdin));

    close(fd[0]);

    execl("program_A", NULL);

    perror("exec"); 
    exit(1);

} else {

    close(fd[0]);
    write(fd[1], sendarray, 2*sizeof(char*));
    close (fd[1]);

    int status; 

      if (wait(&status) != -1) {

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {


            printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));


        } else {
          perror("wait");
          exit(1);
        }
      }


}







return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that it is aconventional not to tell the program what it is called.  Your `execl()` line should be `execl("program_A", "program_A", (char *)NULL);`.  The first argument is the path name of the file to be executed (`programA` in the current directory), and the second is the value in `argv[0]` of the executed program.  Note that there is nothing to stop you using `execl("progam_A", "hypothetical-misnomer", (char *)NULL);` giving it an `argv[0]` value unrelated to the path name.

Answer (score 1):

You are piping the wrong data to the child process.

I am assuming `var_a` and `var_b` are the strings you want to send to program A. They are both of type **array of chars**, which in C is the **same thing** as **pointer to char** (Actually there is a small difference between pointers and arrays but this is irrelevant for this problem). So they are actually just pointers to the first byte of each argument. `sendarray`, however is an **array of char-pointers** which is the **same thing** as a **pointer to char-pointer**. Keep this in mind for a second.

When calling `write()` the 2nd parameter tells it where the data is in memory. By passing `sendarray`, write thinks this `sendarray` points the data you want to write although it actually points to yet another pointer. So what happens is that the pointer values of `var_a` and `var_b` (which is what `sendarray` points to), are written to the pipe.

So you have to pass `var_a` and `var_b` to `write()`, since those are pointers to the actual data you want to send. Also you have to know how long (how many bytes) this data is. If `var_a` and `var_b` point to null-terminated strings, you can use `strlen()` to determine their length.

One last thing: I don't know how exactly your program A obtains 2 arguments from a continuous byte stream like `stdin`, but assuming it reads it line by line, you obviously have to send a new-line character from program B, as well.

So putting it all together your write statements should look something like this:

```
write(fd[1], var_a, strlen(var_a));
write(fd[1], "\n", 1);
write(fd[1], var_b, strlen(var_b));
```

Of course, if any of the assumptions I made is wrong, you have to adopt this code appropriately.

Comment: The newline isn't needed — probably — because the `fgets()` calls preserve the newlines in the input data (probably).  There are caveats about overlong lines, etc, and null bytes in the middle of an input line, and various other possible glitches that can mostly be ignored.

Comment: `fgets()` reads one line from the input but also stores the new-line character in the result.

Comment: btw. there are manual pages for all the C functions, where details like this are explained. Type `man 3 fgets` in you terminal or goolge to view them. ;-)

Comment: Your code sends three lines to the program; my impression is that it only expects two lines.  Hence the middle `write()` is not wanted.  It isn't absolutely clear ('a program A that takes two arguments from stdin' is not using the normal terminology; they're lines of input rather than command line arguments), but …

Comment: goolge --> Google if you're quick.  You can edit comments for up to five minutes.

Comment: My code sends two lines to the program (unless the strings `var_a` and `var_b` contain `\n`-characters themselves). `write()` doesn't append a line-break character (`\n`) at the end, so one write call does not correspond to one line written to the pipe.

Comment: As written, the code uses `fgets()` twice to read two lumps of data.  Assuming the input lines are both shorter than 255 characters including the newline, your writing code will pass the lines plus the newlines, and interpolates an extra newline.  If the data did not end with newlines, then you send one line and an incomplete line; you'd need a second 'write newline' operation after writing `var_b`.